# Can an implicit interface cast cause null with a COM object?

Tags: c#, .net, com, nullreferenceexception

I got an intermittent ArgumentNullException I can't understand.

the code looks something like

```cs
COMRow row = GetCOMRow();
DoSomething1(row);
DoSomething2(row);
DoSomething3(row);
...
// DoSomething methods all look like this:
void DoSomethingX(ICOMRow row)
{
    if (row == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(row));
    ...
}

// the com interface
[ComImport]
[Guid("...")]
[TypeLibType(TypeLibTypeFlags.FDual | TypeLibTypeFlags.FNonExtensible | TypeLibTypeFlags.FDispatchable)]
[SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity]
public interface ICOMRow { ... }

[ComImport]
[Guid("...")]
[CoClass(typeof(COMRowClass))]
public interface COMRow : ICOMRow { }
```

The stack trace says ArgumentNullException happens in `DoSomething3`!

How can the row variable be null in `DoSomething3` when it wasn't in `DoSomething2`?

There is an implicit cast from `COMRow` to `ICOMRow` in the call. Will this lead to a COM `QueryInterface` which fails for some reason and silently returns null?

The COM object can sometimes be unstable (COMException) so I understand QueryInterface can fail but want to learn if that is happening here or if I need to look elsewhere.

Comment: You'd need to show how you cast `COMRow` to `ICOMRow`. To my knowledge casting an object to an interface is unsafe. The interface doesnt implement `COMRow`, since `COMRow` already implements `ICOMRow`

Comment: Since DoSomethingX casts the COMRow object into an interface, at least one call to `QueryInterface` happens each time you enter the method. In interop scenarios with native code involved, anything can basically happen. In any case, the root cause resides inside COMRow implementation. Difficult to say more w/o some reproducing code.

Comment: @SimonMourier, Roe, thank you for your replies. It is not my COM object so I have no idea how it looks inside. The exception is intermittent and not reproducable. I just see it in logs.
COMRow is not an object. It is an interface which inherits from IComRow (don't know why COM interop works it that way. The actual object is probably COMRowClass). Using a derived interface as base interface would normally be a NOP, that is why I asked if COM interop works differently. So my real question is probably if using a derived interface as base interface call QueryInterface.

Comment: No, COMRow is a COM object (CoClass). This object implements ICOMRow. The "interface" here is misleading, this is all metadata generated by .NET tooling. I mean, for your question, this doesn't change anything, the problem is in the COM object.

Comment: If `QueryInterface` can fail then all bets are off. There is no guarantee of anything working correctly. Yes technically it's in spec for a COM object to decide at whim whether to allow `QueryInterface`, but it's not expected.

Comment: @SimonMourier, I understand. I'll change the type of the row variable to be ICOMRow. Then it should only be one call to QueryInterface and hopefully the problem disappears or I get a "normal" com error instead. Add an answer saying something like "yes, queryinterface is called whenever COMRow is cast to ICOMRow and I'll except it.

Comment: I'm not sure this is a valid answer for me, but you can answer yourself if you're happy so far :-)